# Where ngrx keeps state data

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I am just wandering where Ngrx keeps state data. Is it just in memory storage, or it uses localStorage or indexDB? I mean how it stores the state when the app refreshes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default its in memory only. There are packages that allow support for persistence on the client.

IndexDB:
https://github.com/ngrx/db

LS:
https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage